# Smooth shadows between two close objects

Tags: mesh, objects, shadows

[image: 2 different objects]

Is it possible to avoid this shadow break without merging objects and their meshes? I really don't want to, because it's much easier to work with parts, than one big mesh.

Comment: could you show another screenshot? it's hard to understand what's happening...

Comment: @moonboots Just two cylinder-like objects placed one over one, making single pipe. https://pasteboard.co/J8kZNGd.png